# How can I return string as char* from a function in cpp?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-strings, return-type, stdstring

for instance,

if `str = "ab"` is passed in a function `returnString()`

and we have a function defination like

```
string returnString(string str) 
{
    str+='c';
    return str;
}
```

Output :- `abc`

but if we have function  as

```
char* returnString(string str) 
{
    str+='c';
    return str;
}
```

will give the error like :

```
[Error] cannot convert 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'char*' in return***
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You almost never want to work with `char*` in C++. For safety and convenience you should use `std::string` but for a C-style interface you should at least use `const char*` so you can say `str.c_str()` but you have to be really careful of object lifetime, for example in your `returnString` calling `str.c_str()` will return a dangling pointer to the internal array from the function-local string that fell out of scope.

Comment: This is [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain why do you need to return `char *`? Most probably there is better way to solve your `X` problem then `Y` which you have answer for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.data()` or `str.c_str()` to get a pointer to the first character, **but you should never return this outside of your function**. You are inviting a very swift access violation once your string gets destroyed (look carefully, `str` is a local copy on the function's stack), and that's if you're lucky.

If you're trying to interface with a C API, you can `strdup` that pointer before exiting the function, but make sure you understand that the new pointer needs to be `free`d at some later point by you.

Comment: The function `strdup` is not part of the ISO C or C++ standard library. It is a platform-specific function (e.g. POSIX). Note that the question is not tagged with a specific platform. Therefore, you may want to recommend using [`std::strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) instead, as that function will work on all ISO C++ compliant platforms. However, most common platforms do seem to support `strdup`, so I am upvoting the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion from the type `std::string` to the type `char *` or `const char *`.

So the compiler issues the error

```
[Error] cannot convert 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'char*' in return
```

You could declare and define the function the following way.

```
const char * returnString( std::string &str ) 
{
    str += 'c';
    return str.c_str();
}
```

The function changes the passed object of the type `std::string`.
The returned pointer will be valid while the referenced object of the type `std::string` is alive and is not changed.

Otherwise you need to allocate dynamically a character array. In this case the function could be defined for example like

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

char * returnString( const std::string &str ) 
{
    auto n = str.length();

    char *p = new char[ n + 2 ];

    std::memcpy( p, str.c_str(), n );

    p[n] = 'c';
    p[n+1] = '\0';

    return p;
}
```

You will need to remember to delete the allocated character array when it will not be required any more using the operator `delete []`.

Comment: @TimRandall Thanks. I have updated the phrase.